# How to put an empty body for a int value in XML in Java using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm learning about XML and Java using JAXB. And the XML should look like this:

```
<order>
   <product>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>samsung</name>
   </product>
</order>
```

This is the Product class:

```
public class Product{
    private int id;

    @XmlElement
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

In another class I need to set the id field and I'm doing a comparision and if id is different than another field called prodId then id will be initialized with prodId, but if id is equal with prodId than the value should be empty in the XML:

```
<order>
   <product>
     <id></id>
     <name>samsung</name>
   </product>
</order>
```

So, I'm doing something like this:

```
if (product.getId() != prodId) {
   prod.setId(prodId)
} else if (prod.getId() == prodId) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the id in product class to Integer

```
public class Product{
    private Integer id;

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and then you can do something like this.

```
if (product.getId() != prodId) {
   prod.setId(prodId)
} else if (prod.getId() == prodId) {
   prod.setId(null)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karim, if I do that the tag <id></id> disappear completely, I want the tag to be there, but the value should be empty.